# How to output a single value from an array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have some SQL that does a bog standard search and then in the controller (INDEX.PHP) stores these results into an array. An extract is shown below:

INDEX.PHP Extract

```
    foreach ($s as $row)
    {
        $results[] = array(
                            'id' => $row['id'],
                            'name' => $row['name'],
                            'gender' => $row['gender'], 
                            'county' => $row['county'], 
                            'constituency' => $row['constituency'], 
                            'qualifications' => $row['qualifications'],
                            'bio' => $row['bio'],
                            'monday' => $row['monday'],
                            'tuesday' => $row['tuesday'],
                            'wednesday' => $row['wednesday'],
                            'thursday' => $row['thursday'],
                            'friday' => $row['friday'],
                            'saturday' => $row['saturday'],
                            'sunday' => $row['sunday'],
                            'filename' => $row['filename'],
                            'mimetype' => $row['mimetype']
                            );
    }
    include 'profiles-small.html.php';
    exit();
```

Then in the 'profiles.html.php' page I use a foreach loop to output my results as follows:

PROFILES-SMALL.PHP extract

```
    <?php if (isset($results)): ?>

    <?php foreach ($results as $result): ?>

    <h1 class="margin-top">Search Results for <span class="red"><?php htmlout($result['constituency']); ?></span></h1>

    <ol class="small-profile">

    <img class="small-img" src="<?php if (!empty($result['filename'])) echo('?action=view&id=' . $result['id']); else echo "/img/profile_coming_soon.jpg" ?>" width="100" height="100" />

    <li><?php htmlout($result['name']); ?></li>

    <!--<li class="list-left2">Constituency:</li>-->
    <li><?php htmlout($result['constituency']); ?></li>

    <li><?php htmlout($result['qualifications']); ?></li>

    </ol>

    <form action="?" method="post">

    <div id="buttons">

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php htmlout($result['id']); ?>">

    <a href="?more&id=<?php htmlout($result['id']); ?>">View full profile</a>

    <!--<input type="submit" name="action" value="Edit" class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Delete" class="deletebutton">-->

    </div>
    </form>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Now in that above extract there is a h1 tag that should only be shown once at the top of the page.

I know that because it is in the foreach loop, for each result this h1 tag will also be output.

The thing is and I know it is probably very simple but I am unsure of how to output this value above the loop so it is just displayed once.

The value is in an array called $results so I thought I could use the following:

```
<?php htmlout($results['constituency']); ?>
```

Now looking at this, I can see this doesn't make sense because that $results array could contain several constituency results.

Even if several results are returned, they will all contain the same constituency value so I guess I am looking for something like either:

- A loop that returns unique values (Don't think this exists)
- A way in the controller (INDEX.PHP) to store this constituency as a variable that I output.

The second options is probably the way to go however then I have another issue with this.

The PHP that I have learnt so far always outputs the results into an array.  So I would have something like:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pt";

$s = $pdo->query($sql);
```

Then I would use as shown previously above:

```
foreach ($s as $row)
{
    $results[] = array(.........
```

How can I just store the result of a query into a variable?  E.g.

```
$constituency = "SELECT name from constituency WHERE id = $constituencyid";

$s = $pdo->query($constituency);

    $result = $s (Not allowed as this is a PDO object but hopefully you can see what I am thinking)
```

Okay really appreciate any help that anyone can give me on this.

Comment: Why not place the `<h1>` tag before the `foreach` and below the `if(isset...` condition. Then you can `print` `constituency` there as `$results[0]['constituency']`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a PHP function called `array_unique()` you should have a look at over at the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the below function to get an array of `constituency`

```
$constituencies  = array_map(function($val){
  return $val['constituency'];
}, $results);
```

Use the below code to get `constituency` in a variable

```
$sql = "SELECT name from constituency WHERE id = ".$pdo->quote($constituencyid);
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$row  = $stmt->fetch();
$constituency = $row['name'];
```